Why can't I increase my GPU utilization?
I have a simple UNet model (~1M params) written in Keras 3.0.1, running with a torch backend. My CUDA version is 12.3. When I train using GPU on a HPC, it only utilizes 12% of it. Even the memory usage of the GPU is low. No matter how much I increase the batch size, training time or GPU utilization do not change. Why is it? What am I doing wrong?

Show us the code you're running. If we can reproduce the 12% utilization, we'll be in a better position to offer helpful remarks.

You may have a bottleneck when loading or preprocessing your data, before sending them to the GPU.

I do all the preprocessing beforehand and have the data in memory. Is there such a thing as copying it to GPU memory? I am using Keras.util.Pydataset class's child class to feed it to the model.

Again, please show us the actual code especially the lines where the GPU is enabled.
